# Rails and JavaScript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of undefined at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am very new to combining Rails and JavaScript and I am trying to display error messages in a pop-up window. I am working with devise and my user rgistration form is a multistep form. Users_controller create action looks like this:

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to user_steps_path
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js do
          render template: 'registrations/failed_modal.js.erb',
                 layout: false,
                 locals: { error_messages: @modal.errors } 
        end
    end
  end
```

I have a form in views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb. In this form you can also see, that I already defined my modal window, inkl. the styles in CSS, which, I think, are not relevant here.

```
<div class="container">

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="modal-body">
        // errors will display here with javascript code
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center-items-register">
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), remote: true) do |f| %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

      <div class="row 1">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'required' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="column">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :last_name, class: 'required' %><br />
            <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row 2">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="field email">
            <%= f.label :email, class: 'required' %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email", class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row 3">
        <div class="column">
          <div class="field">
            <%= f.label :password, class: 'required' %>
            <% if @minimum_password_length %>
            <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
            <% end %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control' %><br />
          </div>
        </div>

          <div class="column">
            <div class="field">
              <%= f.label :password_confirmation, class: 'required' %><br />
              <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      <div class="row buttons">
        <div class="column buttons">
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit "Sign up", class: 'btn form margin' %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>

        <div class="column buttons">

          <% if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
            <%= link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) %><br />
          <% end %>
          <%= link_to fa_icon("facebook", text: "Sign up with facebook"), user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-social btn-facebook" %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the devise/shared folder I have _error_messages.html.erb.

```
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <h2>
      <%= I18n.t("errors.messages.not_saved",
                 count: resource.errors.count,
                 resource: resource.class.model_name.human.downcase)
       %>
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In the folder views/devise/registrations I have created failed_modal.js.erb, to which I reffer in my Users_Controller with this line:

```
render template: 'registrations/failed_modal.js.erb',
```

The failed_modal.js.erb has following content:

```
var errors = <%= error_messages.to_json.html_safe %>; 

var errorForm = document.querySelector('#myModal'); 

Object.keys(errors).forEach(function(prop) {
  var modalBody = error_form.querySelector('.modal-body');
  var errElement = document.createElement('div');
  errElement.classList.add('alert');
  errElement.classList.add('alert-danger');
  errElement.innerText = prop + ':' + errors[prop][0];
  modalBody.appendChild(errElement)
})

errorForm.style.display = "block";
```

Also I created a new file in assets/javascripts/new.js and I do have //= require_tree in my application.js. The content of my new.js file as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
  var modalBody = document.querySelector(".modal-body");

    span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    modalBody.innerHTML = "";
  };

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      modalBody.innerHTML = "";
    }
  };
});
```

When I now click on the "sign up"-button in my form I get the error described in the title of the question. What am I doing wrong? This code was created with some copy-paste help and I kind of understand what is happening. There are however some thoughts on this, I have:

```
locals: { error_messages: @modal.errors }
```

I tried `@user.errors` and also `resource.errors` - seems not to be affecting anything. So I don't know if `@modal.errors` is right here.

In `failed_modal.js.erb` there is `var errorForm = ...` but in the line below the code is

```
var modalBody = error_form.querySelector('.modal-body');
```

Could this be a mistake?

When I run this in the browser, console tells me the error is in `span.onclick = function()` line. But I assume, there are more errors, as nothing happens when I click "sign up" at all.

[image]

Comment: What is the initial style of `<div id="myModal" class="modal">`? If it has `display: none` then `document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];` will be undefined on page load...

Comment: It was set to none. I changed it, but this is still not working, displaying the same error.

Comment: Is the close button actually on the page then? What happens if you open dev tools and type `document.getElementsByClassName("close")` ?

Comment: Oh, I really don't know where and how to do this

Comment: Just in the console where you see the error

Comment: I added image to the question above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206074/discussion-between-katharina-schreiber-and-dbramwell).